# Former MD/PhD student looking to apply again to MD or MD/PhD

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am a nontraditional applicant for MD or MD/PhD programs and wanted to ask questions about my application here.

I spent six years at another MD/PhD program. I have various publications at the top journals (Cell, Science, Nature). I had a mental health crisis that resulted in some abnormal behavior. It led to me withdrawing from that MD/PhD program, but I have spent two years recovering.

I maintain a strong interest in academic medicine and I am ready to take another go at it.

How might my application be processed differently? How successful could an applicant like myself be? Do you have advice on how I can present myself in the best manner?

Thanks very much for your time.